# Problems using SQL Server JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, left-join

I have two tables with some equals fields and one field that makes the difference:

Table One - Ingresaron

```
DepartmentId Fecha_Lunes Entraron
------------ ----------- -----------
26           2022-08-01  1
26           2022-08-15  2
26           2022-08-22  3
26           2022-08-08  3
```

Table Two - Salieron

```
DepartmentId Fecha_Lunes Salieron
------------ ----------- -----------
26           2022-08-15  3
26           2022-08-22  4
26           2022-08-08  2
26           2022-08-29  1
```

I'm looking for query that returns a result set like this:

```
DepartmentId Fecha_Lunes Salieron   Entraron
------------ ----------- ---------- -----------
26           2022-08-01  null       1
26           2022-08-08  2          3
26           2022-08-15  3          1
26           2022-08-22  4          2
26           2022-08-29  1          null
```

But no matter what combinations of JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, CROSS JOIN I can not solve it, can you help me please?

Comment: Seems you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. It would really help if you *showed* us your attempts and *explained why* they aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full join would do:

```
select coalesce(ing.DepartmentId, s.DepartmentId) as DepartmentId,
   coalesce(ing.Fecha_lunes, s.Fecha_lunes) as Fecha_lunes,
   s.Saileron,
   ing.Entraron
from ingresaron ing
full join saileron s on ing.departmentId = s.DepartmentId and ing.Fecha_lunes = s.Fecha_lunes;
```

**EDIT**

2022-08-29 has no problem, it's not excluded. See the [dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba268878415ae671098586631d74de19)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and example, but it does seems to work,  because when I apply a full outer join  like this a record for the date 2022-08-29 gets excluded....

Comment: @RodrigoFulanito see the link in the comment.

Comment: Yes! I was using it wrong, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

See my example code below:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
DepartmentId INT
, Fecha_Lunes DATE
, Entraron INT)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
DepartmentId INT
, Fecha_Lunes DATE
, Salieron INT)

INSERT INTO table1
VALUES (26, '2022-08-01', 1)
, (26, '2022-08-15', 2)
, (26, '2022-08-22', 3)
, (26, '2022-08-08', 3)

INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (26, '2022-08-15', 3)
, (26, '2022-08-22', 4)
, (26, '2022-08-08', 2)
, (26, '2022-08-29', 1)

SELECT ISNULL(t1.DepartmentId, t2.DepartmentId) AS DepartmentId
, ISNULL(t1.Fecha_Lunes, t2.Fecha_Lunes) AS Fecha_Lunes
, t1.Entraron
, t2.Salieron
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.DepartmentId = t2.DepartmentId
    AND t1.Fecha_Lunes = t2.Fecha_Lunes
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: This example look promissing, but it the result set had the same problem that Vlookup answer, because I have to use for the join the condition 

`code` t1.departmentid = t2.departmentid and t1.fecha_lunes=t2.fecha_lunes `code`

Comment: Try my code again, I edited it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would think a full outer join would work for this giving you everything from table one and table two joining on date and dept id.

```
SELECT DepartmentId Fecha_Lunes Entraron, Salieron          
FROM [Table One - Ingresaron] A         
FULL OUTER JOIN [Table Two - Salieron] B
ON A.DepartmentID = B.DepartmentID 
AND A.Fecha_Lunes = B.Fecna_Lunes
```